# I want to overlap 2 ImageView so I can see both

Tags: android

I have an ImageView that it's a background with an arrow. And I have another ImageView that it's the same background but with another different arrow.

I want to show one of the ImageView, and when I press a button, it shows the another ImageView and the first one. I.e. overlap them.

Is there any function to overlap 2 ImageView without use canvas or another?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can call onclick :

```
 if (view1.getVisibility == View.INVISIBLE ) {
    view1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) ;
    view2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
 } else {
    view1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) ;
    view2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 }
```

I don't think there is a function to overlap directly...

Answer (score 0):

XML

```
<LinearLayout android:name="myView">

<ImageView android:name="rightArrow"
     android:src"@+id/drawable/image1">
</ImageView>

<ImageView android:name="leftArrow"
     android:src"@+id/drawable/image2">
</ImageView>

<Button android:name="myButton">

</Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

Code:

```
Button button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.myButton);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

if (imageView1.getVisibility == View.INVISIBLE ) {
    imageView1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) ;
    imageView2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
 } else {
    imageView1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) ;
    imageView2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 }

 }
});
```

Comment: But I want to see both arrows, at the same time. Not change the ImageView. When I press the button, i want to see both, not only te first arrow. Thank you

Comment: set this property via code to see through from top imageView. `Android:alpha="0.5"`

Comment: or like this `imageView1.setAlpha(127);`